# Installing .NET Framework 4 Client Profile - Very Slow

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I am manually installing .Net Framework 4 because this is a fresh install of Windows 7 and Windows Update is being incredibly slow, however I want to use apps that require .Net Framework 4. Everything runs smoothly, if not slowly, until it starts trying to install Client Profile and then the entire thing hangs. It's been at least 30 minutes on this current attempt, an hour on my previous attempt which ended with a reboot.

[image: I]

Comment: have you installed .net 4.6.2? The setup should be faster because framework is smaller

Answer (score 0):

Don't use such on old .net version. [.Net 4.6.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/) replaces all older .Net 4.x releases. [Install this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=53344) to have the latest version.